# Removing duplicate records from a Python list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, iteration

I am obtaining data from a URL and doing some processing on that data.  I have now come to a point where I need to eliminate duplicates.  Below is the output of my program.

```
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} 
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9} 
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} 
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9} 
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} 
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}
```

I want this to be my output:

```
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} 
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} 
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}
```

The @Number can be between 1-7.  What is the best way to approach this problem? Do I need to get the max of @Number and then print as many lines as my max value?

Comment: 1) Are identical entries identical in all respects? That is, are all of the key-value pairs the same? 2) Do you care about the order of the result?

Comment: They are exactly the same.  @Number basically tells me how many unique record I have.  Keeping the order is important.

Comment: Wait, you only want to keep a total of seven rows, one for each value of `@Number`? That's completely different from comparing whole rows. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain a set for the one you have already seen:

```
seen=set()
data=[]
for e in input:
    if e["@Number"] not in seen:
        seen.add(e["@Number"])
        data.append(e)

>>> data
[{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10}, {u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15}, {u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10}, {u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10}, {u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}]
```

If your data is alway in order and your lines will be complete once you print the max, you could do:

```
>>> input[0:max(int(e) for e in (d['@Number'] for d in input))]
[{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10}, {u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15}, {u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10}, {u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10}, {u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}]
```

Comment: The issue is that I do not have my output in a list format.  Each line gets pushed out as it reads the URL.  Is it possible to make a list out of my output?  I tried list[output] but then I get [u'Price', u'@Number', u'Mw'] with no data values.

Comment: Use a for loop on your data with a set. Done. Go public. Assuming it is iterable...  How does the data come to you?

Comment: Sorry..  I am not sure what you mean.. :(

Comment: You say it is not a list of dicts -- OK. You are reading these dics from _____?

Comment: I use requests.get(url). I then do a lot of data manipulation to finally get the output above. What do you mean by: " Use a for loop on your data with a set" ?

Comment: You *probably* iterate over each separate response from the server. This looks like JSON data. `requests.get(url)` returns a requests object back. Iterate over that. You use a `for` loop to iterate in Python. You may need to call something like `requests.get(url).text` [Read about it](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Answer (score 2):

use an `OrderedDict` to maintain order and the  `u'@Number'` as the key only adding if the `u'@Number'` is not already in out dict.

```
l=[{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15},
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9},
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15},
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9},
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15},
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10},
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}
]

from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()
for d in l:
    num =  d["@Number"]
    if num not in od:
        od[num] = d

print(list(od.values())

[{u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10, u'Price': 133.84},
{u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15, u'Price': 139.09},
{u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10, u'Price': 144.34},
{u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10, u'Price': 148.53},
{u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9, u'Price': 152.52}]
```

If the order is always guaranteed as in your example you can simply break when you find a repeated `"@Number"`:

```
for d in l:
    num = d["@Number"]
    if num not in od:
        od[num] = d
    else:
         break
```

If you want to use `max`:

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter

# for @Number" > 9 use lambda
#  mx = int(max(l, key=lambda x: int(x["@Number"]))["@Number"])
mx = int(max(l, key=itemgetter("@Number"))["@Number"])
print(list(islice(l,None,mx)))
```

Comment: Your method of converting to an int in max breaks if there are ever strings of greater than 1 digit it should be noted...

Comment: @dawg, the OP  stated there strings are always 1-7, if not a lambda will work as the key casting to int

Comment: I mention it for a future SO browser who comes along with a list of sorted dictionaries where that field might be something other than the coincidence of the ascii value of the digit is also it max. More than one digit or negative values breaks the code. It does work for the limited case stated by the OP -- acknowledged.

Comment: @dawg, no worries, I added a lambda which will work for any number positive or negative.

Comment: Keep calm and rock on ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This program does what you ask:

```
data = [
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} ,
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9} ,
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} ,
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9} ,
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} ,
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9},
]

result = []
for item in data:
    if item not in result:
        result.append(item)
for item in result:
    print item
```

Output:

```
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10}
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15}
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10}
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10}
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, using OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10}, 
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} ,
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9} ,
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} ,
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9} ,
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15} ,
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10} ,
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}]

od = OrderedDict()

for d in l:
    od[d["@Number"]] = d


print(od)
```

Results is:

```
OrderedDict([('1', {'@Number': '1', 'Price': 133.84, 'Mw': 10}), ('2', {'@Number': '2', 'Price': 139.09, 'Mw': 15}), ('3', {'@Number': '3', 'Price': 144.34, 'Mw': 10}), ('4', {'@Number': '4', 'Price': 148.53, 'Mw': 10}), ('5', {'@Number': '5', 'Price': 152.52, 'Mw': 9})])
```

In the dict, @Number is used as a key. And because it is an OrderedDict, the order of Numbers in the original list preserved.

Comment: This will also actually screw the order

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How? Its the order they appear in the original list.

Comment: This gives you the last set of uniques; his example has the first set of uniques from the list...

Comment: @dawg In this example it does not matter. Prices and Mws values are same for first or last uniques.

Comment: Yes -- I suppose that they are. Anyways, some of the approaches here deliver the first set of uniques; others, like yours, the last set. I guess the OP needs to specify which is correct for his data. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary with Price @Number and Mw as keys.Then check if the new item is already in dict or not.

```
def combine(L):
    results = {}
    for item in L:
        key = (item["Price"], item["@Number"],item["Mw"])
        if key not in results:  # combine them
            results[key] = item
    return results.values()
```

The output

```
{u'Price': 148.53, u'@Number': u'4', u'Mw': 10}
{u'Price': 139.09, u'@Number': u'2', u'Mw': 15}
{u'Price': 152.52, u'@Number': u'5', u'Mw': 9}
{u'Price': 144.34, u'@Number': u'3', u'Mw': 10}
{u'Price': 133.84, u'@Number': u'1', u'Mw': 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data really looks as you describe, and you want to rule out identical triples, the obvious solution would be to convert them to a set. Since order is important, you could use `collections.OrderedDict` instead with a dummy value `True`.

You'll first need to transform your data into tuples, since dictionaries cannot be used as dict keys:

```
mytuples = [ tuple(x["Price"], x["@Number"], x["Mw"]) for x in mydata
```

(or just build your data as tuples to begin with).

Then:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
unique = OrderedDict((tup, True) for tup in mytuples)
```

You can now use `unique.keys()` to retrieve your triplets in the order they were seen.